# NodeJs Check for user input is emoji or collection of strings and emoji(s)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, emoji

I am working on a NodeJs project. The user gives me an input text and accessing it from req.body.info.
I have to check two cases and work according to it:

1. user inputs an emoji
   I use a regex in this case and works fine. I pass the string to check to a function and the code is like

```
let is emoji = function(str){
    console.log(/(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/.test(str));
}
```

It validates almost all emaojis.

2. User inputs a string (with or without emojis)
   If the user input is just a string (say hello, 1, 0, abc etc.) the function above returns false as expected. But in my case This string can contain emojis, and in that case I want to make it matches to false. That is I want a solution to check whether an string is purely emoji(s) (i.e it should evaluate to true in all cases like input string is  or , or even ...). If it contains some text like (I am happy ) in this case the solution should not match to true.

I could only found the solutions to check whether an emoji is present, list out emojis from an input, replace emojis with something else etc.That's not my case.

Hope some one can help.

Comment: You should quantify your regex with `+` and apply `^` and `$` anchors: `^(EMOJI-REGEX)+$` or if you want to allow spaces between them: `^(\s*EMOJI-REGEX)+$`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/o3oESE/1 (the regex matches all emojis from the [Emoji Data for UTS #51 (Version: 11.0)](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-test.txt)).

Comment: @Revo, and Wiktor thank you so much for suggesting these